# How to define a type that only allows a specific string literal from another type?

Tags: typescript

I have defined a string literal type and, for another type, it requires one of the string literals; however only one specific string is accepted in that instance. So now I'm wondering how I can define that.

Example:

```
type MyStrings = 'A' | 'B' | 'C';

// Option 1
type MyOtherType1 = {
  type: MyStrings;
  whatever: string;
}

// Option 2
type MyOtherType2 = {  
  type: 'A';
  whatever: string;
}
```

With Option 1, I keep the reference to the original type; with Option 2 I make sure only the correct type is passed.

Is there something where I can specify only that one string, while still referencing where the type is coming from?

Comment: I think what you want might be the Extract utility type: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/typescript-extracttype-union-utility-type/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way would be to [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) the member you want:

```js
type MyOtherType = {
  type: Extract<MyStrings, 'A'>;
  whatever: string;
}
```

That way you're still using `MyStrings` but, if it is subsequently updated such that `'A'` is no longer a member, although the `Extract` itself wouldn't fail (it would just be `never`) anything trying to assign `'A'` to `type` would start showing an error.

Alternatively, depending on the specific context:

- you could [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) the members you *don't* want (`Exclude<MyStrings, 'B' | 'C'>`), then any subsequently-added members would also be valid values; or
- you could factor out e.g. `type SomeOfMyStrings = 'A'` and make `type MyStrings = SomeOfMyStrings | 'B' | 'C'`.